# Unable to understand how to check the existing session in PHP

Tags: php, session

The code mentioned below, always displays message "New session" where as session id is same old one. can someone guide me how to properly detect an old session?

```
<?php
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
    echo "New session..... " . $_SESSION['session_id'] . "<BR>";
} else {
    echo "Old session..... " . $_SESSION['session_id'] . "<BR>";    
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not just `start_session()` it will sort it all out behind the scenes

Comment: @RiggsFolly some additional processing is required if its a new session :(